# Exporting the output of sqoop into a text file and storing in variable

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I am trying to get the max of column in oracle table and trying to get the max value of it  into a text file onto local machine.

I am using the below command:
sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:url -username -password 
--query"select max(col_name) from test" >> data.txt

I am getting the following output:

---

### | Max(col_name)               |

### | 156              |

I am looking for just the number in the output file as:

156

Nothing other than the value found. How can i achieve it?

Comment: In this particular case, you could pipe the output into `tr -d` and have it delete everything which is not a digit. See _man tr_.